# FileNotFound Exception MediaPlayer android

Tags: android

I have a1.ogg in the res/raw file

```
try {
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a1);      
} catch (Exception e)
{ Log.e("msg",e.getMessage());  }
```

Give me java.io.FileNotFoundException

The same file in wav format work

Comment: the above code worked for me... PS. I created a media player in onCreate()... I was able to play that file too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=424):

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

mp.setDataSource("/data/test.ogg"); // replace with correct location
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```